# Equality in JOIN or WHERE clause? Efficiency and style

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-standard

Of the two queries below, which is the most efficient for postgresql?
And which has better style in terms of readability, etc.

The difference is the placement of the statement `doctor.type != 'surgeon'`

Inside the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT practice.name, doctor.name 
FROM doctor 
JOIN practice ON (doctor_code = code) 
WHERE doctor.name LIKE '%son' 
AND (doctor.type != 'surgeon');
```

or inside the JOIN clause:

```
SELECT practice.name, doctor.name
FROM doctor
JOIN practice ON (doctor_code = code AND doctor.type != 'surgeon')
WHERE doctor.name LIKE '%son';
```

Comment: In your first query, the brackets aren't necessary, so I'd remove those. I prefer the first style, but it's just a preference.

Comment: And it's better to use the table names (or aliases) to prefix the columns everywhere, e.g.: `practice.doctor_code = doctor.code`

Answer (score 5):

Speaking of **style**, you can improve in several places:

In addition to what Craig already wrote.

- It's inconsistent to have one condition that only involves the `doctor` table in the `JOIN` clause, while the other one is in the `WHERE` clause. Be **consistent**, both or none. Best to put these in the `WHERE` clause, while the condition that links both tables goes into the `JOIN` clause - possibly simplified using `USING`. See below.
- It's also inconsistent to table-qualify some columns (`doctor.name`, `doctor.type`), but not others (`code`). In bigger queries it's best to **always table-qualify** all columns to avoid naming collisions and make the code clear.
- <strike>"name"</strike> is **not a good name**. You should rarely use it. Use meaningful identifiers that you don't repeat in every table. Once you join a couple of tables (which is what you do in SQL *all the time*), you end up with multiple columns named "name" and have to deal out column aliases to even work with it. "id" or "code" are similarly bad choices.
  Use descriptive identifiers as suggested below.
- It's an anti-pattern to use `doctor.code` and `practice.doctor_code`. Some not-so-smart ORMs are in the habit of using this - doesn't make it a good idea. In addition to "code" being a poor identifier, it's good practice to use the *same* name for columns with *identical* data. Use `doctor_code` in both places. Or rather: **`doctor_id`** because it's probably an "identifier" not a "code" (wrong term). Such a naming convention also allows to use the convenient [`USING` construct in joins](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).
- Use the SQL standard **`<>`** instead of the (also supported) `!=`.
- Use **table aliases** to shorten code and maintain readability.

Everything put together, it could look like this:

```
SELECT p.practice, d.name  -- for a person, "name" is halfway sensible
FROM   doctor d
JOIN   practice p USING (doctor_id)
WHERE  d.name LIKE '%son'
AND    d.doc_type <> 'surgeon';
```

Answer (score 2):

None of those parentheses are necessary.

Efficiency is identical for an inner join (so long as you're under `join_collapse_limit`). For join-lists bigger than PostgreSQL's join-reordering limit the extra terms in the `ON` predicate may be faster though.

Focus on style. Is it logically a part of the condition that joins one table to another? Put it in the `ON` predicate. Is it unrelated? Put it in the `WHERE` clause.